# How to view PageView data within Google Analytics Campaign reports

Tags: google-analytics, page-views, campaigns

I'm sending up a bunch of campaign data to GA along with the pageview information.
I cant see any way of viewing the campaign information while showing what page the results have originated from.

Am I missing something here? It seem like crucial functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more than 2 dimensions - i.e. more than campaign, and page as your secondary dimension, you have several options. As a custom report within GA, as a Google studio report, or using the Google Sheets GA add-on, or the Analytics Edge add on with Excel.

Comment: Or, to compare numbers, one could use up to four segments that reflect marketing channels/campaigns. And the pivot option for the data table also allows for a few more options.